# Open / Close Bootstrap accordion with different buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-accordion

I'm hoping someone can help. I have a jsfiddle set up here - https://jsfiddle.net/henry_ivory/Lr3n5pjw/

Here's that fiddle as a snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.collapse-link-1', function(e) {
  //alert("open accordions-->");
  $('.collapseOne').collapse('toggle');
});

$(document).on('click', '.collapse-link-2', function(e) {
  //alert("open accordions-->");
  $('.collapseTwo').collapse('toggle');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="product-title" style="width:100%;text-align:center;color:black;">
    <h3>Email</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-group" id="LHS">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="L1" class="collapsed  collapse-link-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#collapseOne_L">LHS1</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <!--/.panel-heading -->
            <div id="collapseOne_L" class="panel-collapse collapseOne collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Welcome LHS1
                </div>
                <!--/.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!--/.panel-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="L2" class="collapsed  collapse-link-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#collapseTwo_L">
                        LHS2
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <!--/.panel-heading -->
            <div id="collapseTwo_L" class="panel-collapse collapseTwo collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Welcome LHS2
                </div>
                <!--/.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!--/.panel-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel-group" id="RHS">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="L1" class="collapsed  collapse-link-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#collapseOne_R">
                        RHS1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <!--/.panel-heading -->
            <div id="collapseOne_R" class="panel-collapse collapseOne collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Welcome RHS1
                </div>
                <!--/.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!--/.panel-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="L2" class="collapsed collapse-link-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#collapseTwo_R">
                        RHS2
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <!--/.panel-heading -->
            <div id="collapseTwo_R" class="panel-collapse collapseTwo collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Welcome RHS2
                </div>
                <!--/.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!--/.panel-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: structure]

if a user clicks on the title (email etc) or the product name or logo then all panels within that section (email etc) will need to open at once, and collapse. Also pressing the + on the bar will cause the 4 panels to expand and collapse.

the amount of panels may increase in each section so needs to be scalable. I think I'm close but my javascript skills are limited!

Comment: A fiddle is nice, but Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make your code runnable **on-site** is even better. When you use an external site, you run the risk of leaving critical information out of your question (questions can't rely on off-site content). Using Stack Snippets markedly improves your chances of getting useful answers. (As does formatting your code so it's not massively indented and off the right-hand side of the page.)

Comment: I've copied the fiddle into the question for you and done the formatting. (Oddly, the "Tidy" button in the snippet editor really didn't like those links; may be worth checking you don't have an unclosed tag or two somewhere.)

Comment: Thanks for the help @T.J.Crowder!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```
<script>
$(function()
{
var boolean="true";
var timesRun = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    timesRun += 1;
$(".panel-collapse,.panel-title a").attr("aria-expanded","true");
$(".panel-collapse").addClass("in");
$(".panel-title a").addClass("collapsed");
console.log(timesRun);
    if(timesRun === 2){
$(".panel-collapse,.panel-title a").attr("aria-expanded","false");
$(".panel-collapse").removeClass("in");
$(".panel-title a").removeClass("collapsed");
        clearInterval(interval);
    } 
}, 1000); 
$(".product-title h3").click(function()
{
if(boolean)
{
$(".panel-collapse,.panel-title a").attr("aria-expanded","true");
$(".panel-collapse").addClass("in");
$(".panel-title a").addClass("collapsed");
boolean=false;
}
else
{
$(".panel-collapse,.panel-title a").attr("aria-expanded","false");
$(".panel-collapse").removeClass("in");
$(".panel-title a").removeClass("collapsed");
boolean=true;
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the script it's so close, I just noticed 1 bug in it, maybe you can help? if you open then close with one of the panel titles (say product1) and then try to open with the section heading (email), the panel description text appears but the panels themselves don't animate - any idea's why this could be?

Comment: Dont know why class '.panel-collapse collapse'  always having style attribute with 'height: 0'. i posted another answer. Check if it is working fine or not?

Comment: Yes it is working now thanks! I just need to have several sections like this now, is it possible to scale this code? So each section works independently?

Comment: I have marked as useful :) could you give an example of when you say 'use your section name or id before ".panel-collapse"' for having multiple sections?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one.

```
<script>
$(function()
{
function panel_show()
{
$(".panel-collapse,.panel-title a").attr("aria-expanded","true");
$(".panel-collapse").addClass("in");
$(".panel-collapse").removeAttr("style")
$(".panel-title a").addClass("collapsed");
}
function panel_hide()
{
$(".panel-collapse,.panel-title a").attr("aria-expanded","false");
$(".panel-collapse").removeClass("in");
$(".panel-collapse").removeAttr("style")
$(".panel-title a").removeClass("collapsed");
}
var bool="true";
var timesRun = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    timesRun += 1;
panel_show()
console.log(timesRun);
    if(timesRun === 2){
panel_hide();
        clearInterval(interval);
    } 
}, 1000); 
$(".product-title h3").click(function()
{
if(bool)
{
panel_show();
bool=false;
}
else
{
panel_hide();
bool=true;
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, works great. Any ideas how I could scale this to include several separate sections that work independently of each other?

Comment: Yes. Please use your section name or id  before ".panel-collapse".

Comment: here is an updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/henry_ivory/Lr3n5pjw/1/

Comment: Could you give an example of how to have 2 sections that work independently?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one but note that you have to separate your sections by using two `div`

```
<script>
$(function()
{
function panel_show(curr_sec)
{
$("#" +curr_sec +" .panel-collapse").attr("aria-expanded","true");
$("#" +curr_sec +" .panel-title a").attr("aria-expanded","true");
$("#" +curr_sec +" .panel-collapse").addClass("in");
$("#" +curr_sec +" .panel-collapse").removeAttr("style")
$("#" +curr_sec +" .panel-title a").addClass("collapsed");
}
function panel_hide(curr_sec)
{
$("#" +curr_sec +" .panel-collapse").attr("aria-expanded","false");
$("#" +curr_sec +" .panel-title a").attr("aria-expanded","false");
$("#" +curr_sec +" .panel-collapse").removeClass("in");
$("#" +curr_sec +" .panel-collapse").removeAttr("style")
$("#" +curr_sec +" .panel-title a").removeClass("collapsed");
}
var bool="true";
var timesRun = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    timesRun += 1;
$(".panel-collapse,.panel-title a").attr("aria-expanded","true");
$(".panel-collapse").addClass("in");
$(".panel-collapse").removeAttr("style")
$(".panel-title a").addClass("collapsed");
console.log(timesRun);
    if(timesRun === 2){
$(".panel-collapse,.panel-title a").attr("aria-expanded","false");
$(".panel-collapse").removeClass("in");
$(".panel-collapse").removeAttr("style")
$(".panel-title a").removeClass("collapsed");
        clearInterval(interval);
    } 
}, 1000); 
$(".product-title h3").click(function()
{
var bool="true";
var curr_sec=' ';
var prev_sec=' ';
$(this).closest('div').parent('div').attr("id","Current_Section");
curr_sec = $(this).closest('div').parent('div').attr("id").toString();
$(this).closest('div').parent('div').siblings().attr("id","Prev_Section");
prev_sec=$(this).closest('div').parent('div').siblings().attr("id").toString();
$(this).toggleClass("Selected");
$(this).closest('div').parent('div').siblings().find("h3").removeClass("Selected")
if($(this).hasClass("Selected") === true)
{
panel_show(curr_sec);
panel_hide(prev_sec)
}
else
{
panel_hide(prev_sec)
panel_hide(curr_sec);
}
});
});
</script>
```

Here is your HTML Code:

```
<div id="section1">
<div class="product-title" style="width:100%;text-align:center;color:black;background-color:#3c4d5a;">
       <h3 style="padding:5px;color:white;margin-bottom: 0;">Email</h3>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#23ff7c;">In my Data Centre</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#2691fa;">As a service</div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <!-- First Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="service-logo" style="float: left;"><img src="assets/scc.jpg"  class="img-responsive" style="max-height:37px;margin-right: 10px;"></div>
         <div class="panel-heading" style="border-radius: 0px;">

          <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
           <div class="service-title">Product or Service Title</div>
          </h4>
          <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" />

         </div>
         <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
           <ul>
            <li>Highlight One</li>
            <li>Highlight Two</li>
            <li>Highlight Three</li>
           </ul>
           <div class="service-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div> 
           <div class="service-extras" style="">Datacentres located in: <b>France</b></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Second Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="service-logo" style="float: left;"><img src="assets/scc.jpg"  class="img-responsive" style="max-height:37px;margin-right: 10px;"></div>
         <div class="panel-heading" style="border-radius: 0px;">
          <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">
           <div class="service-title">Product or Service Title</div>
          </h4>
          <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" />
         </div>
         <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
           <ul>
            <li>Highlight One</li>
            <li>Highlight Two</li>
            <li>Highlight Three</li>
           </ul>
           <div class="service-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div> 
           <div class="service-extras" style="">Datacentres located in: <b>France</b></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <!-- First Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="service-logo" style="float: left;"><img src="assets/scc.jpg"  class="img-responsive" style="max-height:37px;margin-right: 10px;"></div>
         <div class="panel-heading" style="border-radius: 0px;">
          <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour">
           <div class="service-title">Product or Service Title</div>
          </h4>
          <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" />
         </div>
         <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
           <ul>
            <li>Highlight One</li>
            <li>Highlight Two</li>
            <li>Highlight Three</li>
           </ul>
           <div class="service-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div> 
           <div class="service-extras" style="">Datacentres located in: <b>France</b></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Second Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="service-logo" style="float: left;"><img src="assets/scc.jpg"  class="img-responsive" style="max-height:37px;margin-right: 10px;"></div>
         <div class="panel-heading" style="border-radius: 0px;">
          <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive">
           <div class="service-title">Product or Service Title</div>
          </h4>
          <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" />
         </div>
         <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
           <ul>
            <li>Highlight One</li>
            <li>Highlight Two</li>
            <li>Highlight Three</li>
           </ul>
           <div class="service-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div> 
           <div class="service-extras" style="">Datacentres located in: <b>France</b></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
            <div id="section2">
            <div class="product-title" style="width:100%;text-align:center;color:black;background-color:#3c4d5a;">
       <h3 style="padding:5px;color:white;margin-bottom: 0;">another heading</h3>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#23ff7c;">In my Data Centre</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#2691fa;">As a service</div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <!-- First Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="service-logo" style="float: left;"><img src="assets/scc.jpg"  class="img-responsive" style="max-height:37px;margin-right: 10px;"></div>
         <div class="panel-heading" style="border-radius: 0px;">

          <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
           <div class="service-title">Product or Service Title</div>
          </h4>
          <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" />

         </div>
         <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
           <ul>
            <li>Highlight One</li>
            <li>Highlight Two</li>
            <li>Highlight Three</li>
           </ul>
           <div class="service-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div> 
           <div class="service-extras" style="">Datacentres located in: <b>France</b></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Second Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="service-logo" style="float: left;"><img src="assets/scc.jpg"  class="img-responsive" style="max-height:37px;margin-right: 10px;"></div>
         <div class="panel-heading" style="border-radius: 0px;">
          <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">
           <div class="service-title">Product or Service Title</div>
          </h4>
          <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" />
         </div>
         <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
           <ul>
            <li>Highlight One</li>
            <li>Highlight Two</li>
            <li>Highlight Three</li>
           </ul>
           <div class="service-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div> 
           <div class="service-extras" style="">Datacentres located in: <b>France</b></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <!-- First Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="service-logo" style="float: left;"><img src="assets/scc.jpg"  class="img-responsive" style="max-height:37px;margin-right: 10px;"></div>
         <div class="panel-heading" style="border-radius: 0px;">
          <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour">
           <div class="service-title">Product or Service Title</div>
          </h4>
          <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" />
         </div>
         <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
           <ul>
            <li>Highlight One</li>
            <li>Highlight Two</li>
            <li>Highlight Three</li>
           </ul>
           <div class="service-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div> 
           <div class="service-extras" style="">Datacentres located in: <b>France</b></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Second Panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="service-logo" style="float: left;"><img src="assets/scc.jpg"  class="img-responsive" style="max-height:37px;margin-right: 10px;"></div>
         <div class="panel-heading" style="border-radius: 0px;">
          <h4 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive">
           <div class="service-title">Product or Service Title</div>
          </h4>
          <input type="checkbox" style="float:right" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" />
         </div>
         <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
           <ul>
            <li>Highlight One</li>
            <li>Highlight Two</li>
            <li>Highlight Three</li>
           </ul>
           <div class="service-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div> 
           <div class="service-extras" style="">Datacentres located in: <b>France</b></div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is great! I appreciate your time looking into this

Comment: Welcome anytime :)